# how do I load specific fields from a recordset into a combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, ado, transpose, vba

I have the below code which essentially loads the first field of my recordset into my **Emp ID** combo box by using Transpose, and Recordset .GetRows.

```
    If m_adoStaffRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    With m_adoStaffRS
        .MoveFirst
        cboEmpID.Clear
        cboEmpID.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.GetRows)
        '
        .MoveFirst
        '
        ' TROUBLE HERE >>>
        cboNameSelect.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.GetRows(Fields = .Fields("FirstName").Value & " " & .Fields("LastName").Value))
        '
    End With
    m_lnRecordID = 0
    cboEmpID.ListIndex = 0
End If
```

Now I want to add another *Search* combo box to enable the user who doesn't know an EMp ID to search by name.

So I want to add the firlds **FirstName, LastName** from the recordset but it isn't working.

here is what I tried inside my code above:

```
cboNameSelect.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.GetRows(Fields = .Fields("FirstName").Value & " " & .Fields("LastName").Value))
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Philip

Comment: I would think you are looking for something more along the lines of `cboNameSelect.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.GetRows(Fields = {"FirstName", "LastName"}))` so my syntax for creating the array of strings might be wrong but I think you should pass the Fields option an array of field names (not values). Then I would guess that before you put it in the combo-box you'll need to combine the two columns of the result to make a 1D array (using `& " " &` like you were trying), but you'll probably have to use a loop for that.

Comment: yeah, it looks like a loop is the straightforward answer. thanks

Comment: Once you have it working, please post the code as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value you pass as *Fields* parameter to **GetRows()** is wrong. According to MSDN doc:

> Fields
>
> This optional parameter is a Variant and specifies a single field name or ordinal position or an array of field names or ordinal position numbers. ADO returns only the data in these fields.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee266344.aspx

So one has to pass an array of two elements in order to get only two fields. A code for this would be:

```
With m_adoStaffRS
    .MoveFirst
    Dim FullNames As Variant
    Dim FieldsToSelect(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    FieldsToSelect(0) = "FirstName"
    FieldsToSelect(1) = "LastName"

    FullNames = .GetRows(Fields := FieldsToSelect)

    ' Now fill combo-box using desired format
    cboNameSelect.Clear
    For i = LBound(FullNames) To UBound(FullNames)
        cboNameSelect.AddItem FullNames(0, i) & " " & FullNames(1, i)
    Next i
End With
```

As a side note. It's often more straightforward to do required concatenation (FirstName & LastName) a bit earlier when querying a data source.

Comment: +1 thanks for that, I picked up something that I'd forgotten!